# Change UISearchBar/Keyboard Search Button Title

Tags: iphone, button, uisearchbar, title

In the UISearchBar control, is the a way to change the Search key title for the keyboard to Done?

Comment: Here i explained http://stackoverflow.com/a/26712861/2981840

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For a searchbar named tablesearchbar:

```
// Set the return key and keyboard appearance of the search bar
        for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [tableSearchBar subviews]) {

            if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {

                @try {

                    [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
                    [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
                }
                @catch (NSException * e) {

                    // ignore exception
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Will this get past the App Store approval process?

Comment: As no private APIs are accessed, approval should not be withheld

Comment: Great answer. Extra caveat: instead of using @try-@catch (which we know in objective-C aren't so cheap and well optimized), I would prefer adding a second condition to the if statement:
&& [searchBarSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]
in order to get rid of the @try-catch.

Comment: Looping over subviews didn't work for me in iOS 7, but looping over subviews of subviews did (see my answer).

Comment: //if you're not on the main thread, insert this after 'setReturnKeyType': ______ 

[(UITextField *)searchBarSubview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadInputViews) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: Not working for me, I have posted [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577158/uisearchbar-returnkeytype-not-working-for-ios-8). Please help me

Answer (score 52):

At least for iOS 8, simply:

```
    [self.searchBar setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

Answer (score 43):

As of iOS 7 beta 5, Run Loop's answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
for(UIView *subView in [searchBar subviews]) {
    if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
         [(UITextField *)subView setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyDone];
    } else {
        for(UIView *subSubView in [subView subviews]) {
            if([subSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
                [(UITextField *)subSubView setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyDone];
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, the reason if/else is used is the if is for iOS 6 backward compatibility and the else is for iOS 7.

Answer (score 18):

One more useful hint, to the **Run Loop** code (in "@try") section.

This enabled "Done" button when text field is empty:

```
UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)searchBarSubview;
tf.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works with the solution of Gregory for iOS7.

Answer (score 18):

**For Swift to change return key of UISearchBar**

```
searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
```

**enum available are as below**

```
public enum UIReturnKeyType : Int {

    case default
    case go
    case google
    case join
    case next
    case route
    case search
    case send
    case yahoo
    case done
    case emergencyCall
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case continue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminder! If you searchBar stays as first responder, after you change your returnKeyType, you need to dismiss your keyboard and pop it up again to see the changes.

```
search.resignFirstResponder()
searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
search.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is a protocol with optional methods, you should test each method separately instead of try-catching.

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        // keyboard appearance
        if ([searchBarSubview respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeyboardAppearance:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarSubview setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        // return key 
        if ([searchBarSubview respondsToSelector:@selector(setReturnKeyType:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarSubview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        // return key disabled when empty text
        if ([searchBarSubview respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
        // breaking the loop when we are done
        break;
    }
}
```

This will work for iOS <= 6. For iOS >= 7, you need to loop in `searchBar.subviews[0].subviews`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Alert-style keyboards are semi-transparent, I can see my view behind it. It doesn't look very good since I have multiple elements behind the keyboard that makes it hard for the keys to stand out. I wanted an all-black keyboard.

So I animated a black UIImageView into position behind the keyboard when text is edited. This gives the appearance of an all-black keyboard.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25]; 

    blackBoxForKeyboard.frame = CGRectMake(0, 377, 320, 216);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions shown here, and none of them worked for my UISearchBar (xcode5 compiling for iOS7). I ended up with this recursive function which worked for me:

```
- (void)fixSearchBarKeyboard:(UIView*)searchBarOrSubView {

    if([searchBarOrSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        if ([searchBarOrSubView respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeyboardAppearance:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarOrSubView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        if ([searchBarOrSubView respondsToSelector:@selector(setReturnKeyType:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarOrSubView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        if ([searchBarOrSubView respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:)])
            [(id<UITextInputTraits>)searchBarOrSubView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
    }

    for(UIView *subView in [searchBarOrSubView subviews]) {
        [self fixSearchBarKeyboard:subView];
    }
}
```

I then called it like so:

```
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[self fixSearchBarKeyboard:_searchBar];
```

Comment: With Xcode 5 + iOS7, text input will be in a sub-subview instead of a subview. So basically you used my Xcode 4 solution and added a recursive call. For best performances, you can test for iOS version, and if it's iOS7, you browse through `subviews[0].subviews` instead of `subviews`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for covering all the iOS versions:

```
NSArray *subviews = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7 ? _searchBar.subviews : _searchBar.subviews[0].subviews;

for (UIView *subview in subviews)
{
    if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
        [textField setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        break;
    }
}
```