# iphone - Search button on a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a search functionality using UISearchBar that occurs on-the-fly, so I think it would be more obvious to replace that "Search" button on the keyboard with "Done".

Is there a way to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `keyboardType` property of your UISearchBar object. However, there is not a way to change the `returnKeyType` directly. You may be able to filter down and change it manually. Check the documentation for UISearchBar and see if you can find `returnKeyType` as that is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the search bar doesn't have this property... :(

Answer (score 2):

I accomplish it this way:

```
// --   Basic UISearchBar setup.
self.theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,38)];
[self.theSearchBar setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.theSearchBar];

// --   Customize the returnKeyType of the search bar's nested UITextField.
UITextField *searchBarTextField = [[self.theSearchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
searchBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

Hope that is helpful.  This approach (i.e. grabbing a subview by index) may break in the future, but it works fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in _searchBar.subviews){
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class] ]) {
                UITextField *searchTf = (UITextField *)view;
                searchTf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for iOS 6

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = [[searchBarObj subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
    searchBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;

    [searchBarTextField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
```

This is working for iOS 7

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
{
    for (UIView *subSubview in subview.subviews)
    {
        if ([subSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subSubview;
            [textField setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't rely on it being the second subview, use isKindOfClass: method to check. It will be more iOS update proof that way.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.theSearchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField *)subview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
        break;
    }
}
```