# UISearchBar Keyboard Return Key

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a UISearchBar to match text input against entries in a database and display the matched results to the user in a UITableView, as they type.

All is well, however, I cannot find a way to alter the return key type of the search bar's keyboard. By default it replaces the standard <kbd>return</kbd> key with a <kbd>Search</kbd> button. Because I am doing a live search as the user types, I do not need this button and having it there and inactive has raised some usability issues.

**Attempted solutions**

1. I can set a keyboard with the `setKeyboard:UIKeyboardType` method, however this doesn't seem to override the default setting of replacing the return key (on the standard keyboard) with a <kbd>Search</kbd> key and it does not allow access to change this <kbd>return</kbd> key.
2. I have thought about using a `UITextField`, giving me access to the `returnKeyType` property through the `UITextInputTraits` protocol. My problem with this however is that I am implementing the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`, which I would lose with the `UITextField`.

Is there a way that I can keep the functionality of the search bar's delegate methods, whilst having legitimate access to the keyboard's return key?

In fact, almost the exact screen I am implementing is found in Apple's Clock application
Screenshot:
[image]

So any help on a clean solution would be much appreciated. Note the <kbd>return</kbd> key on the bottom right instead of the default <kbd>Search</kbd> button'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35147293/569789

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    }
}
```

If you want to dismiss the return key (i.e., make it do nothing), set the "returnKeyType" property on the UITextField subview to "UIReturnKeyDone" along with "keyboardAppearence".

Comment: Many thanks @Neo, an effective solution. UIView class reference does seem to warn against this approach:
_"For complex views declared in UIKit and other system frameworks, any subviews of the view are generally considered private and subject to change at any time. Therefore, you should not attempt to retrieve or modify subviews for these types of system-supplied views. If you do, your code may break during a future system update."_
Is this approach App store safe? Thanks

Comment: Andy.. I know at least a couple of other developers who did this without facing any problems.. Also, we are only testing for the presence of a certain class. So it is App store safe because we are not using any private Apis.

Comment: Thanks for solution! Can I please know where to put this code? Bcoz I tried in search bar begin edtiong and also in viewDidLaod, but didnt work for me.

Comment: I put the code in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing and it worked.

Answer (score 20):

Slightly different in iOS 7 compared to the answer of @sudip.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
{
    for (UIView *subSubview in subview.subviews)
    {
        if ([subSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subSubview;
            [textField setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: was looking for this answer as the old ones don't work anymore in iOS 7, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. In order to make the Done key actually dismiss the keyboard, I also had to set the view controller as the delegate of the text field (before setting the returnKeyType) and implement a textFieldShouldReturn delegate method that includes [textField resignFirstResponder].

Comment: I also found that I had to change the textField's delegate back to the UISearchBar in searchBarTextDidEndEditing, using another set of loops like those shown above. Otherwise if I dismissed the keyboard and then tried to edit the search text again, it wouldn't take the focus and become editable the second time.

Comment: @arlomedia No need to deal with setting/unsetting UITextField delegate, you can still listen to searchBarSearchButtonClicked: of UISearchBarDelegate. One additional thing that I needed, though was textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO; to have Done available on empty text.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this now ?

Answer (score 20):

I tried all of these solutions without luck until I realized that in IOS8, you can just set `searchBar.returnKey = .Done` or whatever `UIReturnKeyType` you like. Sigh.

Comment: thanks buddy, this has worked for me: searchBar.returnKeyType = .Done

Answer (score 2):

I had to add some lines to Neo's answer. Here is my code to add a "Done" button for UISearchbar :

```
for(UIView *subView in sb_manSearch.subviews) {
    if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {

        UITextField *t = (UITextField *)subView;
        [t setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

        t.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        t.delegate = self;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change Search into Done text.
Use below code.

```
youtSearchBar.returnKeyType = .done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     // Adding observer that will tell you keyboard is appeared.
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];        

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    keyboardTest = [self getKeyboard];

    [keyboardTest setReturnKeyEnabled: YES];
}

- (id) getKeyboard  // Method that returns appeared keyboard's reference 
{
    id keyboardView;

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;

    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) 
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) 
        {           
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
            {
                keyboard = [[keyboard subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
                keyboardView = keyboard ;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                keyboardView = keyboard ;
        }

    }
    return keyboardView ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :** From iOS 7 onwards, ***the accepted answer will not work***, below version will the work on iOS 7 onwards.

```
 UIView *subViews =  [[_searchBar subviews] firstObject];
        for(UIView *subView in [subViews subviews]) {
            if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
                [(UITextField *)subView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)subView;

        @try {

            [txt setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
            [txt setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {

            // ignore exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -1):

I just found the simplest wait to hack this, just put a blank when beginning editing search field

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    //Add a blank character to hack search button enable
    searchBar.text = @" ";}
```

Comment: This answer enables the Search button, but the OP wanted to change it to Return or Done.