# Unrecognized selector when calling `[UISearchBar setReturnKeyType:]`

Tags: ios, selector, uisearchbar

In our app we started getting the following error for iOS 7.0, 7.0.4 and 7.0.6 users:

`-[UISearchBar setReturnKeyType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178a7920`

It took us a bit to figure out what was going on, since Xcode 6.4 no longer supports 7.0, 7.0.4 and 7.0.6 simulators.  The explanation is shared below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We realized from the documentation in `UISearchBar.h` that:

> ...UISearchBar officially conformed to `UITextInputTraits` in iOS 8.0  and privately conformed in iOS 7.0...

So 8.x have public / full support for `UITextInputTraits` but 7.x versions of iOS only have private / potentially partial support for it.

We started playing with the different iOS 7.x versions and found out that those equal or greater than iOS 7.1 do support `setReturnKeyType:`, while earlier versions do not.

It seems [a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583463/uisearchbar-keyboard-return-key) was used in early versions of iOS 7 (see the second most popular answer in the link), which seemed to validate our conclusions.

So for iOS 7.x versions we ended up using this:

```
if ([searchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setReturnKeyType:)]) {
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; // Pick a type
} else {
    // Call the method from the linked answer above for iOS < 7.1
    // or leave the return key type unchanged.
}
```

Comment: But "privately conformed" is still conformed. The subsequent sentence "Prior to 7.0, UISearchBar only implemented these four traits: autocapitalizationType, autocorrectionType, spellCheckingType and keyboardType. If your deployment target is <7.0 and you are using any trait other than one of the four mentioned, you must check its availability with respondsToSelector:" implies that a check should only be needed for 6.x and before, not 7.0. They should update their comment to say 7.1, not 7.0.