# Change UISearchBar/Keyboard Search Button Title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm trying to do the equivalent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705865/change-uisearchbar-keyboard-search-button-title/2706081#2706081) but in Swift and I'm running into problems:

1. No equivalent of `try/catch` blocks in swift
2. The `if` statement never seems to be evaluated as true

Here is what I've put together so far:

```
for searchBarSubview in self.searchBar!.subviews {
    if (searchBarSubview.conformsToProtocol(UITextInputTraits)) {
        var searchBarTextField = searchBarSubview as UITextField
        searchBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you only need to do the following code and you are good to go. Any reasons why that bothers you to check `UITextInputTraits`?

```
[self.searchBar setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

Answer (score 9):

**To change return type of UISearchBar in swift**

```
searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
```

**Other Enum**

```
    case Default
    case Go
    case Google
    case Join
    case Next
    case Route
    case Search
    case Send
    case Yahoo
    case Done
    case EmergencyCall
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case Continue
```