# How do I change Text Input Action Button (return/enter key) on Keyboard in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In *Android and iOS* it is possible to change the *enter/return* key  of the **keyboard** to e.g. a "*Go*" button (and other options).

[image: illustration]

On **top**, we can see the regular "*Return*" button on both systems, which is the one you get by default with no modifications in both Android & iOS native and Flutter.

**Below** that, there is another setting, again on both systems, which you can simply adjust in your native application. It is the "*Go*" button in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415284/change-uisearchbar-keyboard-search-button-title-in-swift but different enough that I didn't vote. I don't believe your question is related to Flutter. You just wanna know how to change the title of the Enter.

Comment: @StephenJ The question you have linked is only for **native iOS**, not Flutter and I am not sure if this is even `IME` related.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was "like Flutter" more than literally "in", misinterpreted

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The **input action** for a `TextField` (or `TextFormField`) can be specified like this (here, the *Go* button):

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go
  ...
)
```

***[List of all available input actions.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputAction.html#constants)***

Comment: Looks like it might be done already: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18855.

Comment: and what about physical keyboard because i've tried this one but its not working for physical keyboard when the user press enter from physical keyboard it's not working

Comment: This solution works for Android. For iOS it only works for TextInputType.text and not for TextInputType.number

Answer (score 90):

This is how you can use `textInputAction`:

```dart
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    print("search");
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
    hintText: 'Search ',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to add the action button and also listen to onTap

For TextField

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    print("Go button is clicked");
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
  ),
);
```

For TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
      print("Go button is clicked");
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Type your search here",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
          ),
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 16.0)),
    )
```

Answer (score 7):

This is currently not possible.
Although you can edit flutter sources to make it possible quite easily.

The following edits are :

> flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart

Change `_openInputConnection` line ~430 to

```
void _openInputConnection() {
  if (!_hasInputConnection) {
    final TextEditingValue localValue = _value;
    _lastKnownRemoteTextEditingValue = localValue;
    _textInputConnection = TextInput.attach(this,
        new TextInputConfiguration(
            inputType: widget.keyboardType,
            obscureText: widget.obscureText,
            autocorrect: widget.autocorrect,
            inputAction: widget.keyboardType == TextInputType.multiline
                ? TextInputAction.newline
                : TextInputAction.done
        )
    )..setEditingState(localValue);
  }
  _textInputConnection.show();
}
```

In the same file, also declare a new field on `EditableText` class (not the state one) ~line 280

```
final TextInputAction textInputAction;
```

And assign it in `EditableText` constructor above line 164

```
this.textInputAction,
```

---

> flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart

Same story. Add a new field, but to `TextField` instead :

```
final TextInputAction textInputAction;
```

and add the following to it's constructor :

```
this.textInputAction,
```

Finally, pass that new field as parameter to `EditableText` line 479 :

```
    textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
```

---

Done.

You can now inside your app specify a custom `TextInputAction`. This won't break existing `TextField`. It just adds the ability to override the default behavior.

```
new TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
),
```

Comment: Try the same thing. But replace `textInputAction` with `actionLabel`.

Comment: Just to make this clear. I did not find a solution with this. So I do not have a "*Go*" button in my app.

Comment: That code allows you to separately set keyboard type (email, phone number, ...) and the enter button. But in the end, in flutter there's currently only 2 enter icon available : newline, and a check icon.

Comment: Yes, I realized that some time ago. That is why I am asking the question. My bounty message even states that I am just looking for a solution. You are only saying that with your way I cannot get the `Go` button. I am sure there are ways, maybe only natively.

Comment: You'll have to do the change I made above. Then add new values to the `TextInputAction` enum corresponding to the icon you want ("go").  And then support the new values inside flutter engine [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TextInputAction&type=).

Comment: That's probably complicated though as flutter engine is outside of flutter's repo. Better simply creating an issue listing the required icons.

Comment: Not really. This code adds the ability to change the return button icon ; which is a required step for your answer. The missing piece is edits inside flutter engine to support `TextInputAction.go`.

Comment: Enter key icon is choosed by flutter engined based on `TextInputAction`. This code add the ability to change `TextInputAction` on textfield. Now flutter engine need to support new `TextInputAction` values.

Comment: There's nothing SO users can do for you. This is a job for flutter team as like I said this requires edits on flutter engine (not the dart side) to support more icons. Followed by the changes listed here, to allow icon customisation.

Answer (score 5):

basically we are use two types of text input fields,
**TextField** and **TextFormField**,

so,

for TextField,

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go
  .......
)
```

for TextFormField,

```
TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
           ........
)
```

both have textInputAction property, we can use this

Answer (score 3):

Anyone looking for `UIReturnKeyDone` is like this:

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One angle ... I have not explored all the "keyboardType" options within the TextField (optional parameter of [TextInputType](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html)).

But there are some obvious different keyboards for 'emailAddress' and 'datetime' and 'phone' - one of those options may emit the keyboard that you are looking for ...

Comment: I am not searching for whole keyboard layout changes, but only adjustments regarding the action button.

Answer (score 1):

```
onFieldSubmitted: (value){}

textInputAction: TextInputAction.go
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?