# swift 3 SearchController SearchBar change buttons texts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have to change the words Search and Cancel from the SearchBar(and the keyboard) when I'm using the search controller.

I have already changed the placeholder like this

```
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "My text here..."
```

But I can't find anything useful for Swift considering the searchBar is constructed programmatically.

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Can anyone help?

UPDATE: so far I managed to change the Cancel button text like this:

```
searchController.searchBar.setValue("Anuleaza", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
```

But could not find a way to change the keyboard word for Search with a custom text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705865/change-uisearchbar-keyboard-search-button-title ? You can't really put a custom text on KeyBoard, you have to use on of the available return type...

Comment: @Larme, you are right, add what you said as an answer, not a comment and I will accept it.

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate instead of copying on the answers on the link.